# Unable initialise pub/sub with SparkSession

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-pubsub

SO I'm adding Pub/Sub connector in SparkSession to use spark streaming. But every time it gives error that Pub/Sub data source not found. How to fix it !

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("PubSubSpark") \
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-pubsub_2.11:2.4.0") \
.getOrCreate()

project_number = "********"
topic = "*****"
sub = "*****"

# Read from Pub/Sub into Spark DataFrame
df = spark.read \
    .format("pubsub") \
    .option(f"topic", "projects/{project_number}/topics/{topic}") \
    .option(f"subscription", "projects/{project_number}/subscriptions/{sub}") \
    .load()

# Show DataFrame
df.show()

# Write DataFrame to Pub/Sub
df.write \
    .format("pubsub") \
    .option("topic", "projects/{project_number}/topics/{topic}") \
    .save()

# Stop SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

Upon running this code i get this error.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-e4bd27732667> in <cell line: 15>()
     17     .option(f"topic", "projects/{project_number}/topics/{topic}") \
     18     .option(f"subscription", "projects/{project_number}/subscriptions/{sub}") \
---> 19     .load()
     20 
     21 # Show DataFrame

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)


Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: pubsub. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
```

Comment: What is your spark version?

Comment: @VikasSharma 3.5.1

Comment: Sorry, I got busy with Holi celebrations. So yeah, as I suspected your Spark version is not compatible with the pub-sub jar you are using which is the most probable cause of the error you are getting. FYI if you go to the official [Apache Bahir](https://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/2.4.0/spark-streaming-pubsub/) website - the project is retired::[attic page for more details](https://attic.apache.org/projects/bahir.html). It's better to check out alternatives or use the correct spark version.